# How to know some file is currently executing or not?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu. I have two bash script files. Both will run in parallel. Now I want to continuously monitor on another file that it is running or not.

So any way to find that the file is currently executing or not ?

Comment: are you interested in writing a script for monitoring , or you wish to monitor it by your self? are you familiar with top / htop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerous possibilities, it is a question of creativity...

Some suggestions:

- periodically poll the process list and filter it by name or process id
- start the script with control sockets, as long as the sockets are open the script runs
- use the usual locking strategy in file system.
- have the script do a lifebeat on a regular base, then watch that lifebeat.
- start the script in a series of commands, the moment the script exists the next command will be executed by the calling shell. That one could be a notification script or something.
- have the script do some wiggling on your desktop and watch it yourself.
- start it using `nohup` and watch the log file.
- implement a deamon inside the script and connect periodically.
- open a file from within the script and watch the file system using the `fuser` system call.
- periodically write a token into a file by the monitoring script and have the monitored script remove that token, like a baton.
- call the script using a blocking call. The script executes as long as that blocking call does not return.
- create a singleton strategy on process level and simply try starting it periodically.
- make the monitoring script act as a monitor deamon the executing script connects to. If the connection is terminated the scipt obviously has stopped executing.
- ...

Sorry, this starts getting boring...